# Error 1146 while installing K2 extension

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, installation, sql

While installing [K2](http://getk2.org/index.php) extension, Joomla 3.0, GoDaddy hosting) received error message:

`Table 'iWebazoid.bq1ry_k2_categories' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM bq1ry_k2_categories`

Unable to figure out the meaning.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run this query. Don't forget to change the table name and database name to your's bq1ry_k2_categories.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bq1ry_k2_categories` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `extraFieldsGroup` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `published` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `access` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `params` text NOT NULL,
  `trash` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `plugins` text NOT NULL,
  `language` char(7) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=35 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `bq1ry_k2_categories` (`id`, `name`, `alias`, `description`, `parent`, `extraFieldsGroup`, `published`, `access`, `ordering`, `image`, `params`, `trash`, `plugins`, `language`) VALUES
(26, 'University News', 'university-news', '', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, '', '{"inheritFrom":"0","theme":"","num_leading_items":"8","num_leading_columns":"1","leadingImgSize":"Medium","num_primary_items":"2","num_primary_columns":"1","primaryImgSize":"Large","num_secondary_items":"0","num_secondary_columns":"1","secondaryImgSize":"Large","num_links":"0","num_links_columns":"1","linksImgSize":"XSmall","catCatalogMode":"1","catFeaturedItems":"1","catOrdering":"","catPagination":"2","catPaginationResults":"1","catTitle":"0","catTitleItemCounter":"0","catDescription":"0","catImage":"0","catFeedLink":"1","catFeedIcon":"1","subCategories":"1","subCatColumns":"1","subCatOrdering":"","subCatTitle":"1","subCatTitleItemCounter":"1","subCatDescription":"1","subCatImage":"1","itemImageXS":"","itemImageS":"","itemImageM":"","itemImageL":"","itemImageXL":"","catItemTitle":"1","catItemTitleLinked":"1","catItemFeaturedNotice":"1","catItemAuthor":"0","catItemDateCreated":"1","catItemRating":"0","catItemImage":"1","catItemIntroText":"1","catItemIntroTextWordLimit":"","catItemExtraFields":"0","catItemHits":"0","catItemCategory":"1","catItemTags":"0","catItemAttachments":"0","catItemAttachmentsCounter":"0","catItemVideo":"0","catItemVideoWidth":"","catItemVideoHeight":"","catItemAudioWidth":"","catItemAudioHeight":"","catItemVideoAutoPlay":"0","catItemImageGallery":"0","catItemDateModified":"0","catItemReadMore":"1","catItemCommentsAnchor":"0","catItemK2Plugins":"1","itemDateCreated":"1","itemTitle":"1","itemFeaturedNotice":"1","itemAuthor":"1","itemFontResizer":"0","itemPrintButton":"0","itemEmailButton":"0","itemSocialButton":"1","itemVideoAnchor":"1","itemImageGalleryAnchor":"1","itemCommentsAnchor":"1","itemRating":"0","itemImage":"1","itemImgSize":"Large","itemImageMainCaption":"1","itemImageMainCredits":"1","itemIntroText":"1","itemFullText":"1","itemExtraFields":"0","itemDateModified":"0","itemHits":"0","itemCategory":"0","itemTags":"1","itemAttachments":"0","itemAttachmentsCounter":"0","itemVideo":"1","itemVideoWidth":"","itemVideoHeight":"","itemAudioWidth":"","itemAudioHeight":"","itemVideoAutoPlay":"0","itemVideoCaption":"1","itemVideoCredits":"1","itemImageGallery":"1","itemNavigation":"0","itemComments":"1","itemTwitterButton":"1","itemFacebookButton":"1","itemGooglePlusOneButton":"1","itemAuthorBlock":"0","itemAuthorImage":"0","itemAuthorDescription":"0","itemAuthorURL":"0","itemAuthorEmail":"0","itemAuthorLatest":"0","itemAuthorLatestLimit":"5","itemRelated":"0","itemRelatedLimit":"5","itemRelatedTitle":"0","itemRelatedCategory":"0","itemRelatedImageSize":"0","itemRelatedIntrotext":"0","itemRelatedFulltext":"0","itemRelatedAuthor":"0","itemRelatedMedia":"0","itemRelatedImageGallery":"0","itemK2Plugins":"1","catMetaDesc":"","catMetaKey":"","catMetaRobots":"","catMetaAuthor":""}', 0, '', '*'),
(27, 'Events List 1', 'events-list-1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at ante eu justo ultrices iaculis sit amet non est. Maecenas ac mi dapibus, iaculis ipsum ut, tempor metus.', 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, '', '{"inheritFrom":"0","theme":"events_listing1","num_leading_items":"2","num_leading_columns":"1","leadingImgSize":"Large","num_primary_items":"2","num_primary_columns":"1","primaryImgSize":"Large","num_secondary_items":"0","num_secondary_columns":"1","secondaryImgSize":"Large","num_links":"0","num_links_columns":"1","linksImgSize":"XSmall","catCatalogMode":"1","catFeaturedItems":"1","catOrdering":"","catPagination":"2","catPaginationResults":"1","catTitle":"1","catTitleItemCounter":"1","catDescription":"1","catImage":"0","catFeedLink":"1","catFeedIcon":"1","subCategories":"1","subCatColumns":"1","subCatOrdering":"","subCatTitle":"1","subCatTitleItemCounter":"1","subCatDescription":"1","subCatImage":"1","itemImageXS":"","itemImageS":"","itemImageM":"","itemImageL":"","itemImageXL":"","catItemTitle":"1","catItemTitleLinked":"1","catItemFeaturedNotice":"1","catItemAuthor":"0","catItemDateCreated":"1","catItemRating":"0","catItemImage":"1","catItemIntroText":"1","catItemIntroTextWordLimit":"","catItemExtraFields":"0","catItemHits":"0","catItemCategory":"1","catItemTags":"0","catItemAttachments":"0","catItemAttachmentsCounter":"0","catItemVideo":"0","catItemVideoWidth":"","catItemVideoHeight":"","catItemAudioWidth":"","catItemAudioHeight":"","catItemVideoAutoPlay":"0","catItemImageGallery":"0","catItemDateModified":"0","catItemReadMore":"1","catItemCommentsAnchor":"0","catItemK2Plugins":"1","itemDateCreated":"1","itemTitle":"1","itemFeaturedNotice":"1","itemAuthor":"0","itemFontResizer":"0","itemPrintButton":"0","itemEmailButton":"0","itemSocialButton":"1","itemVideoAnchor":"1","itemImageGalleryAnchor":"1","itemCommentsAnchor":"1","itemRating":"0","itemImage":"1","itemImgSize":"Large","itemImageMainCaption":"1","itemImageMainCredits":"1","itemIntroText":"1","itemFullText":"1","itemExtraFields":"0","itemDateModified":"0","itemHits":"0","itemCategory":"0","itemTags":"1","itemAttachments":"0","itemAttachmentsCounter":"0","itemVideo":"1","itemVideoWidth":"","itemVideoHeight":"","itemAudioWidth":"","itemAudioHeight":"","itemVideoAutoPlay":"0","itemVideoCaption":"1","itemVideoCredits":"1","itemImageGallery":"1","itemNavigation":"0","itemComments":"1","itemTwitterButton":"1","itemFacebookButton":"1","itemGooglePlusOneButton":"1","itemAuthorBlock":"1","itemAuthorImage":"1","itemAuthorDescription":"1","itemAuthorURL":"1","itemAuthorEmail":"0","itemAuthorLatest":"1","itemAuthorLatestLimit":"5","itemRelated":"1","itemRelatedLimit":"5","itemRelatedTitle":"1","itemRelatedCategory":"1","itemRelatedImageSize":"0","itemRelatedIntrotext":"1","itemRelatedFulltext":"1","itemRelatedAuthor":"1","itemRelatedMedia":"1","itemRelatedImageGallery":"1","itemK2Plugins":"1","catMetaDesc":"","catMetaKey":"","catMetaRobots":"","catMetaAuthor":""}', 0, '', '*'),
(33, 'Staff & Administration', 'staff-administration', '', 0, 2, 1, 1, 4, '', '{"inheritFrom":"0","theme":"professors","num_leading_items":"8","num_leading_columns":"4","leadingImgSize":"Large","num_primary_items":"4","num_primary_columns":"2","primaryImgSize":"Medium","num_secondary_items":"4","num_secondary_columns":"1","secondaryImgSize":"Small","num_links":"4","num_links_columns":"1","linksImgSize":"XSmall","catCatalogMode":"0","catFeaturedItems":"1","catOrdering":"","catPagination":"2","catPaginationResults":"1","catTitle":"1","catTitleItemCounter":"0","catDescription":"1","catImage":"0","catFeedLink":"1","catFeedIcon":"1","subCategories":"1","subCatColumns":"2","subCatOrdering":"","subCatTitle":"1","subCatTitleItemCounter":"1","subCatDescription":"1","subCatImage":"1","itemImageXS":"","itemImageS":"","itemImageM":"","itemImageL":"","itemImageXL":"","catItemTitle":"1","catItemTitleLinked":"1","catItemFeaturedNotice":"1","catItemAuthor":"1","catItemDateCreated":"1","catItemRating":"0","catItemImage":"1","catItemIntroText":"1","catItemIntroTextWordLimit":"","catItemExtraFields":"0","catItemHits":"0","catItemCategory":"1","catItemTags":"1","catItemAttachments":"0","catItemAttachmentsCounter":"0","catItemVideo":"0","catItemVideoWidth":"","catItemVideoHeight":"","catItemAudioWidth":"","catItemAudioHeight":"","catItemVideoAutoPlay":"0","catItemImageGallery":"0","catItemDateModified":"0","catItemReadMore":"1","catItemCommentsAnchor":"1","catItemK2Plugins":"1","itemDateCreated":"1","itemTitle":"1","itemFeaturedNotice":"1","itemAuthor":"1","itemFontResizer":"0","itemPrintButton":"0","itemEmailButton":"0","itemSocialButton":"1","itemVideoAnchor":"1","itemImageGalleryAnchor":"1","itemCommentsAnchor":"1","itemRating":"0","itemImage":"1","itemImgSize":"Large","itemImageMainCaption":"1","itemImageMainCredits":"1","itemIntroText":"1","itemFullText":"1","itemExtraFields":"1","itemDateModified":"1","itemHits":"1","itemCategory":"1","itemTags":"1","itemAttachments":"1","itemAttachmentsCounter":"1","itemVideo":"1","itemVideoWidth":"","itemVideoHeight":"","itemAudioWidth":"","itemAudioHeight":"","itemVideoAutoPlay":"0","itemVideoCaption":"1","itemVideoCredits":"1","itemImageGallery":"1","itemNavigation":"1","itemComments":"1","itemTwitterButton":"1","itemFacebookButton":"1","itemGooglePlusOneButton":"1","itemAuthorBlock":"1","itemAuthorImage":"1","itemAuthorDescription":"1","itemAuthorURL":"1","itemAuthorEmail":"0","itemAuthorLatest":"1","itemAuthorLatestLimit":"5","itemRelated":"1","itemRelatedLimit":"5","itemRelatedTitle":"1","itemRelatedCategory":"0","itemRelatedImageSize":"0","itemRelatedIntrotext":"0","itemRelatedFulltext":"0","itemRelatedAuthor":"0","itemRelatedMedia":"0","itemRelatedImageGallery":"0","itemK2Plugins":"1","catMetaDesc":"","catMetaKey":"","catMetaRobots":"","catMetaAuthor":""}', 0, '', '*'),
(34, 'Events List 2', 'events-list-2', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at ante eu justo ultrices iaculis sit amet non est. Maecenas ac mi dapibus, iaculis ipsum ut, tempor metus.', 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, '', '{"inheritFrom":"0","theme":"events_listing2","num_leading_items":"2","num_leading_columns":"1","leadingImgSize":"Large","num_primary_items":"2","num_primary_columns":"1","primaryImgSize":"Large","num_secondary_items":"0","num_secondary_columns":"1","secondaryImgSize":"Large","num_links":"0","num_links_columns":"1","linksImgSize":"XSmall","catCatalogMode":"1","catFeaturedItems":"1","catOrdering":"","catPagination":"2","catPaginationResults":"1","catTitle":"1","catTitleItemCounter":"1","catDescription":"1","catImage":"0","catFeedLink":"1","catFeedIcon":"1","subCategories":"1","subCatColumns":"1","subCatOrdering":"","subCatTitle":"1","subCatTitleItemCounter":"1","subCatDescription":"1","subCatImage":"1","itemImageXS":"","itemImageS":"","itemImageM":"","itemImageL":"","itemImageXL":"","catItemTitle":"1","catItemTitleLinked":"1","catItemFeaturedNotice":"1","catItemAuthor":"0","catItemDateCreated":"1","catItemRating":"0","catItemImage":"1","catItemIntroText":"1","catItemIntroTextWordLimit":"","catItemExtraFields":"0","catItemHits":"0","catItemCategory":"1","catItemTags":"0","catItemAttachments":"0","catItemAttachmentsCounter":"0","catItemVideo":"0","catItemVideoWidth":"","catItemVideoHeight":"","catItemAudioWidth":"","catItemAudioHeight":"","catItemVideoAutoPlay":"0","catItemImageGallery":"0","catItemDateModified":"0","catItemReadMore":"1","catItemCommentsAnchor":"0","catItemK2Plugins":"1","itemDateCreated":"1","itemTitle":"1","itemFeaturedNotice":"1","itemAuthor":"0","itemFontResizer":"0","itemPrintButton":"0","itemEmailButton":"0","itemSocialButton":"1","itemVideoAnchor":"1","itemImageGalleryAnchor":"1","itemCommentsAnchor":"1","itemRating":"0","itemImage":"1","itemImgSize":"Large","itemImageMainCaption":"1","itemImageMainCredits":"1","itemIntroText":"1","itemFullText":"1","itemExtraFields":"0","itemDateModified":"0","itemHits":"0","itemCategory":"0","itemTags":"1","itemAttachments":"0","itemAttachmentsCounter":"0","itemVideo":"1","itemVideoWidth":"","itemVideoHeight":"","itemAudioWidth":"","itemAudioHeight":"","itemVideoAutoPlay":"0","itemVideoCaption":"1","itemVideoCredits":"1","itemImageGallery":"1","itemNavigation":"0","itemComments":"1","itemTwitterButton":"1","itemFacebookButton":"1","itemGooglePlusOneButton":"1","itemAuthorBlock":"1","itemAuthorImage":"1","itemAuthorDescription":"1","itemAuthorURL":"1","itemAuthorEmail":"0","itemAuthorLatest":"1","itemAuthorLatestLimit":"5","itemRelated":"1","itemRelatedLimit":"5","itemRelatedTitle":"1","itemRelatedCategory":"1","itemRelatedImageSize":"0","itemRelatedIntrotext":"1","itemRelatedFulltext":"1","itemRelatedAuthor":"1","itemRelatedMedia":"1","itemRelatedImageGallery":"1","itemK2Plugins":"1","catMetaDesc":"","catMetaKey":"","catMetaRobots":"","catMetaAuthor":""}', 0, '', '*');

ALTER TABLE `bq1ry_k2_categories`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `category` (`published`,`access`,`trash`), ADD KEY `parent` (`parent`), ADD KEY `ordering` (`ordering`), ADD KEY `published` (`published`), ADD KEY `access` (`access`), ADD KEY `trash` (`trash`), ADD KEY `language` (`language`);

ALTER TABLE `bq1ry_k2_categories`
MODIFY `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=35;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would suggest you clean up the SQL dump by removing all comments etc so that only the actual queries are there

Comment: Changed table name to bq1ry_k2_categories into the code. Should I paste the above query under SQL query in database iWebazoid keeping everything else as it is (print screen link for reference http://bit.ly/1xIGp5U).

Comment: @Lodder Could you kindly suggest a way (tutorial) for cleaning up the SQL dump relevant for my purpose as I have little idea about the same.

Comment: @BagraRajeev - I've removed all the rubbish from the SQL dump in this answer and added your table prefix so you can now copy and paste it into PhpMyAdmin ;)

Comment: @Lodder Trying to implement your advise. Pasted above code under 'SQL Query on Database iWebazoid'. On doing so, got message: 'You have to choose at least one column to display' (http://bit.ly/1yORo1Z).

Comment: @BagraRajeev - Your are on the **Query** tab. Go to the **SQL** tab instead, and paste it in there ;)

Comment: @Lodder Got message 'Your SQL query has been executed successfully.' Let me check about 1146 error after installing K2 extension. This problem is not limited to K2. Today morning, tried to install another extension (mod_news_pro_gk5_J!3) and got the same error.

Comment: @BagraRajeev - Have a look at this and fix the database if any errors are shown: http://www.joomlabamboo.com/blog/how-to-joomla/how-to-fix-error-upgrading-to-joomla-3

Comment: @Lodder Getting 1146 error. Under Extension Manager, Database 'Database table structure is up to date.' Under Joomla Update 'No Updates available. You already have the latest Joomla! version, 3.3.6.' Also, not upgraded from Joomla 2.5; fresh Joomla 3.0 site.

Comment: Could anyone suggest any other way to address 1146 error faced in this case as unable to download new applications.

Comment: Take a look at this http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=282559

Comment: @z3r0c001 I understand need to have jos_ as my database prefix. Right now, is bq1ry_ my database prefix? (http://bit.ly/1DRbWGj) If so, do I need to change to jos_?

Comment: Just figured out database prefix bq1ry_ from Joomla backend, Global Configuration, Server option. Tried to change to jos_ which broke the website. Restored after accessing configuration.php from root of C-panel hosting and changing database prefix from jos_ to bq1ry_.

Comment: You need to maintain the same DB prefix throughout site. You cannot change it to any random string. If it is jos_. Then rename the table to jos_k2_categories.

Answer (score 2):

This situation can happen if K2 was installed in the past and not removed correctly or after a failed install attempt.

Have a look with your FTP client for either of the directories below as K2 checks for them to establish if you already have it installed:

```
administrator/components/com_k2
components/com_k2
```

### Option 1

Remove these directories and try to install again and you shouldn't have any problems.

### Option 2

I have also seen in some cases this error display but the K2 extension continued to partially install in that case you can open the extension manager and searched for K2 then uninstalled the **Administrator Component** from the list this will uninstall all the other parts of the K2 system.

After that you should have nothing left of K2 and you will be able to do a fresh install with out errors.