# Can't install K2 component

Tags: component, k2, joomla-3.4

I'm trying to install K2 component, cause it's necessary to launch News Show Pro GK5. But I always have errors connected with tables, like this

> Table 'solitaire.sw_k2_categories' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM
>   `sw_k2_categories`

or

> Table 'solitaire.sw_k2_items' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM
>   `sw_k2_items`

When I manually created first table, it shows another one. It seems that something works incorrect.

Does anyone know how to solve it? I use Joomla 3.4.1, and K2 version 2.6.9.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed QuickStart version, and it solved all problems. Now this problem isn't actual.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL user does not have administrative permissions to check tables.

You can proceed with the installation with a full MySQL administrator, and in a second step assign a different MySQL user with restricted INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT permissions.

Comment: Actually I have root user with all privileges, I checked that again. Moreover, I added all privileges especially to current table. It also doesn't help, I still see the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete the all existing k2 component tables in mysql then once again you can install and check it.
If this doesn't work, then make sure that permissions to the administrator mysql and refer this [Error 1146 while installing K2 extension](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7164/error-1146-while-installing-k2-extension) it will helps